# MySQL, sort integer character by character

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to sort integers character by character?

So the list `[110, 120, 10, 200, 20]` would end up like this:

```
10,
110,
120,
20,
200
```

Comment: What have you tried? Which functions in the documentation did you rule out, and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you cast the integer as a varchar or text value, and order by that cast, it should work.

```
ORDER BY CAST(myField AS CHAR)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT num
FROM your_table
ORDER BY CAST(num as CHAR)
```